# Run some commands in Debian package script from current user

Tags: shell, package, debian

How to run some commands in my installations scripts of deb-package (preinst, postinst, prerm, postrm) not from root but from current user (user that invoked the installation)?

Answer (score 3):

root is the current user. You should never expect that the installation of the package is performed by `sudo`

You can check the `SUDO_USER` environment variable for the user that may have invoked the script, if the installation was performed from the context of a simple `sudo dpkg -i` - sudo may not have been installed, so the installation may have been performed by `su`, which means that the environment variable will not be set.

If you want to invoke scripts as that user you just invert the sudo - viz:

```
sudo -u $SUDO_USER -c <command to invoke>
```

but you need to ensure that you properly know the user that invoked the script - i.e. SUDO_USER could be root!

Typically, though, because you can have an arbitrary number of users on a Linux system, you **should not** do something like this, as it will leave the system in a state where only one user can use the package. You should create state/configuration *on first invocation* as the ordinary user.

Finally, don't expect a GUI, don't expect a terminal on the installation if it's just being shipped as a dpkg.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be `root` in order to install something. If you install per-user configurations, they should normally be installed for all users.

Having said that, look into real vs effective uid.